# IPad orientation support like home screen application icons

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface, screen-orientation

How to make a view with 3x4 thumb ImageViews in portrait mode and 4x3 thumb ImageViews in landscape orientation exactly that looks like 
**The orientation effect in iPad home screen icons change/animation effect from landscape to portrait vice verse..**
I have gone through the app (https://github.com/jarada/myLauncher) but it has the effect that it looks like going to set the frames every time device rotates.

Guide me how to design it a sample tutorial link

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UICollectionViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/Reference/Reference.html), adjust its layout to return the desired sizes & locations for your icons.

[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) can help you create a custom UICollectioViewLayout.

Hope it helps.